# How to convert date of varying formats

Tags: c#, date, date-format

So I have a string that could be a date of varying formats.  I wanted to create a method that tries each one until it is successful, then return the converted date, or throw an error if it matches no formats.  I wrote this:

```
private string ConvertDate(string toConvert)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(toConvert)) { return ""; }

    DateTime date;
    bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(toConvert,
            "MMddyy",
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out date);

    if (!success)
    {
        success = DateTime.TryParseExact(toConvert,
            "MMddyyyy",
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out date);
    }
    if (!success)
    {
        success = DateTime.TryParseExact(toConvert,
            "MM/dd/yy",
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out date);
    }
    if (!success)
    {
        success = DateTime.TryParseExact(toConvert,
            "MM/dd/yyyy",
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out date);
    }
    if (!success) throw new Exception("Date formats are not recognized");

    return date.ToString();
}
```

It works, but I feel pretty silly writing all that, I figure there must be an easier way to check a lot of different date formats in 1 pass.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use `Parse()`/`TryParse()`?

Comment: What does your code return for 02/03/2012. 2nd of march or 3rd of february?

Comment: @L.B Month is always first in all the different formats, so feb 3rd

Comment: @Waldfee I think using the regular TryParse method would choke on dates of MMddyy formats without any dashes or slashes, but there may be a way around it I hadn't figured out.

Comment: @KDiTraglia you are correct, it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is at least easier to maintain.  Although the function name is misleading. It's should probably be something like StandardizeDateFormat.

```
private string ConvertDate(string toConvert)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(toConvert)) { return ""; }

    string[] dateFormats = new string[]{"MMddyy","MMddyyyy","MM/dd/yy","MM/dd/yyyy"};
    DateTime date;
    bool success = false;
    for(int i = 0;i<dateFormats.Length &&!success;i++)
    {
        success = DateTime.TryParseExact(toConvert,
        dateFormats[i],
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out date);
    }
    if (!success) throw new Exception("Date formats are not recognized");

    return date.ToString();
}
```

Edit:  Actually, I would probably simplify it even further like so

```
private string ConvertDate(string toConvert)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(toConvert)) { return ""; }

    string[] dateFormats = new string[]{"MMddyy","MMddyyyy","MM/dd/yy","MM/dd/yyyy"};
    DateTime date;
    for(int i = 0;i<dateFormats.Length ;i++)
    {
        if(DateTime.TryParseExact(toConvert, dateFormats[i], new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            return date.ToString();
    }
    throw new Exception("Date formats are not recognized");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks a lot better.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Assuming `MM` is always first and year is `2000 or later` (for `yy` format)

```
string date = "10/25/2011";
string[] arr = date.ToArray() 
              .Where(ch => ch > 47 && ch < 58 ) //Filter out all but numbers
              .Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray(); 

if(arr.Length >5)
{
   string ISOformattedDate = string.Format( arr.Length == 6 ? 
          "{4}{5}-{0}{1}-{2}{3}T00:00:00" : 
          "{4}{5}{6}{7}-{0}{1}-{2}{3}T00:00:00", arr);
   DateTime mydate = Convert.ToDateTime(ISOformattedDate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I like the other answer a little more since it is a lot more clear what is happening, and allows for dates where month isn't first if it ever comes up.